# Why S3 needs Key permissions when we are using SSE on SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, server-sent-events

[Key Management - Amazon Simple Queue Service](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-key-management.html)

Why S3 needs to be allowed:

```
"Action": [
      "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
      "kms:Decrypt"
],
```

Comment: Are you using S3 to publish events into your SQS queue?

Comment: That is right. My question is if it is server side encryption, why s3 needs key permissions?

Comment: There is nothing that I can find mentioned at the link you provided that says S3 needs to be allowed to do anything... and the actions you included in your question are KMS actions, not S3 actions.  It is unclear what you are asking, so please see if you can clarify this question.

Comment: Imagine S3 sending notification to SQS. If the Sqs is SSE, we need to allow S3 the kms permissions on the key being used, as I mentioned above. My question is "why kms permissions needed for s3, i agree they should be for SQS"